# Internet explorer 10 automatically encodes url in xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-10

Is there a workaround to stop IE10 from automatically encoding url before sending an ajax request?

Here is an example:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', '/index.html#fragment', false); 
req.send(null);
if(req.status == 200)
    console.log("req.responseText: " + req.responseText);
```

The network panel of IE10 F12 developer tool shows that the sent request is

> /index.html%23fragment

My server received this same encoded url.

This doesn't happens with other browsers and the spec clearly says that the browser must drop the fragment from the url before performing the request → http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

Thanks.